# I have a sheet with duplicate data in most, but not all, columns. How can I move all useful data into the first row?

Tags: google-sheets

Here are four example rows on Google Sheets:

| Student ID | Grade | Last Name | First Name | Period | Class | Teacher |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 9 | Smith | John | 1 | Spanish | Sanchez, L. |
| 123456 | 9 | Smith | John | 2 | English | King, A. |
| 123456 | 9 | Smith | John | 3 | PE | Washington, M. |
| 123456 | 9 | Smith | John | 4 | Math | Daniel, C. |

I would like the end result to look something like this:

| Student ID | Grade | Last Name | First Name | Period | Class | Teacher | Period | Class | Teacher | Period | Class | Teacher | Period | Class | Teacher |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 9 | Smith | John | 1 | Spanish | Sanchez, L. | 2 | English | King, A. | 3 | PE | Washington, M. | 4 | Math | Daniel, C. |

Is there any sort of data cleanup that can help me organize my data into one single row? I primarily use Google Sheets for work so it would be most helpful if I can find a solution within Sheets.

I thought I could do data cleanup and exclude the last three rows, but that simply results in all the bottom three rows being deleted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review your question again and make sure that your inputs and desired outputs are well defined and clear with formatted examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TOROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187459?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(data,A2:G5,
       flat,TOROW(data),
       header,{A1,TOROW(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),B1:G1))},
       result,{INDEX(flat,,1),FILTER(flat,flat<>INDEX(flat,,1))},
       {header;result}))
```

[image]

**Edit -** Formula to account for several students:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(ids,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)),
       res,MAP(ids,LAMBDA(id,{id,TOROW(FILTER(B2:H,A2:A=id))})),
       VSTACK({A1,TOROW(IF(SEQUENCE((COLUMNS(res)-1)/COLUMNS(B1:H1)),B1:H1))},res)))
```

Comment: Thank you! How could I edit this function so that it can be done with one table header for multiple students? (For example, 24 rows with information for 6 students).

Comment: we would need REDUCE for that. If you share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) I can show you how to do it.

Comment: Hello! I have created the sample sheet, let me know if you're still able to help me create a formula for rearranging the data. Specifically, I would like to create one row per student while also removing redundant information such as student ID, grade, last and first name.

Comment: please share the link here.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nMvbfsKv9KBQHtlcaUEF2eE2T_UJYzgI92z_ApLmUqQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: did the solution I provide help?